# Finding if a string is contained in another string without "find" in c++

Tags: c++, string

I wrote this program to find if a string is contained in another string (see paragraph below this, I tried to explain what I *want* it to do). When I test it, sometimes it works, most of the times it gives me the error "String subscript out of range". I'm very new to C++, I'd appreciate someone to tell me how can I improve this code or why I'm being dumb, because I really don't get why it doesn't work.

what i want this to do is find if string one can be found in string way;
so i want it to check for every letter of string way if the letter [i] is equal to the first letter of the string one (way[i+0]==one[0]),
and way[i+1]==one[1] and so on for all letters in one.

so for example way = abankjve and one = ank
it takes the first letter in way (a) and gets the first letter in one(a). the're equal. but we see that way[0+1] is not equal to one[1]. so o can't be true.
it goes on like this till it gets to way[2]=a. way[2+0]=one[0]. o is true. then it checks way[2+1]=one[1]. true! then it checks way[2+2]=one[2]. true! then
one is contained in way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string way, one;
    bool o=false;
    cin >> way;
    cin >> one;

    for (int i = 0; i < way.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < one.size(); k++)
        {
            if (way[i + k]==one[k])
            {
                o = true;
             
            }
            
        }
    }
    cout << o << endl;

}
```

Comment: Typically you do that the other way around. I.e. in each iteration of the outer loop you expect a match ( set `o = true`) and break the inner loop on the first mismatched character.  Furthermore you code will produce errors at runtime because you don't check boundaries. What if `i+k > way.size()`?

Comment: A tip, if it compiles explain the program to a rubber duck (or a sibling whom you would love to annoy :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string way, one;
    std::cin >> way;
    std::cin >> one;
    bool found{};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < way.size() - one.size()+1; i++)
    {
        if(one == way.substr(i, one.size())) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << found;

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6jc4oY)

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, `way[i+k]` will result in index out of range.
say `way` is length of 5 and `one` is length of 3.
`i+k`'s range is `0 <= i + k <= 6`. Witch is bigger than the possible index of `way`.

change first for loop `for (int i = 0; i < way.size(); i++)` to
`for (int i = 0; i <= (int)way.size() - one.size(); i++)`

Note I've used static_cast to `int`. `*.size()` returns `unsigned int` so if `one`'s size is bigger than `way`'s size, the result won't be what you've imagined.

Comment: _"Not I've used `static_cast` to..."_ No, you used C-style cast (even if the effect is the same here).